# Can orientdb graph database work?

Tags: android, orientdb, graph-databases

Does orientdb graph work on android? I need to use orientdb graph database that work on android locally without any server or cloud. Please tell me if its possible.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Mind to do your own research?

Answer (score 1):

a few years ago some community users tried to do a porting of OrientDB for Android, you can look the project [here](http://wuman.github.io/orientdb-android/) and the git [here](https://github.com/wuman/orientdb-android) but it was never completed.
So I think it's not possible sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using Linux on android (like Userland)
I've successfully installed it using UserLAnd/Ubuntu however couldn't say if it'll work stable.